# "invalid blocks" error with user select in slack block kit

Tags: java, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

```
 app.command("/hello", (req, ctx) -> {
            List<LayoutBlock> blocks = asBlocks(
                    section(section -> section.text(markdownText("select the meeting option"))),
                    actions(actions -> actions.elements(asElements(multiUsersSelect(b -> b.actionId("users-select").placeholder(plainText("select a option"))))))
            );
            return ctx.ack(blocks);
        });
```

This is my code. On `/hello` command , multi user select menu should appear but instead I am getting this error `/hello failed with the error "invalid_blocks"`.

I have also given `users:read` permission for bot.

What could be the reason?

***Update:***

I was able to make it work with this code

```
section(section -> section.blockId("select-users").text(markdownText("*Select Users*")).accessory(multiUsersSelect(select -> select.actionId("select-user-action").placeholder(plainText("Select users that should recieve your survey")))))
```

Comment: looks good to me. Does a simple ctx.ack("select the meeting option") work? have you narrowed down which part of your code causes the issue? how about app.command("/ping", (req, ctx) -> {
  return ctx.ack(asBlocks(
    section(section -> section.text(markdownText(":wave: pong"))),
    actions(actions -> actions
      .elements(asElements(
        button(b -> b.actionId("ping-again").text(plainText(pt -> pt.text("Ping"))).value("ping"))
      ))
    )
  ));
}); [from the manual](https://slack.dev/java-slack-sdk/guides/bolt-basics)?

Comment: The code you mentioned in the comment is working fine. The problem is happening while using multiUsersSelect or multiChannelsSelect with in the actions.

Comment: ok. remember to add the solution as an answer to the question, and mark it as accepted, if it fixed your problem.